# Can a Moderator Step in? This user is removing all of the question text

Tags: support, status-completed, edits

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258875/brian) has removed all of the question text from his questions and replace it with, "This has been fixed."

I've rolledback a few, but there are 24 more questions to go and he's actively rollingback other people's rollbacks to his rollbacks.  Can a moderator step in and restore these questions and disassociate them from this user in case he doesn't want them associated with his account anymore?

Comment: Account is now under 24-hour suspension.

Comment: @Jon Yea, I was telling the people in Chat that I blinked and he was suspended.  I hadn't thought the moderators would do that, but I can see why. He was actively rolling back after people would edit.  Hopefully he cools down or at least asks for directions.

Comment: Yeah, we'll have to watch what happens when the penalty box door opens.

Comment: And apparently he's just studying for a midterm and asking  questions from the sample exam...

Comment: @Jared: Maybe he thought he was covering his tracks. ::chortles::

Comment: @jared how do you know that?

Comment: Hm, I saw this user two (?) days ago, wrote a long comment to him about how to use the site properly and the next thing I knew the entire question had been deleted. For what it's worth.

Comment: @George See his comment from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868459/java-stack-help), also seen here in a screenshot (in case it gets deleted): http://i.imgur.com/KidxJ.png

Comment: @George and I see now that Random quoted him as well in his answer below.

Comment: Always funny to see "can a mod intervene" from someone who later got a diamond. Congrats on that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking for possible motivation and the spurs, we hark back to 26 September 2010, a moderately sunny day with chance of hail and tornado.

In [Count the distinct characters in a string in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796158/scheme-string-help) we have these comments:

> If this is homework, please say so and also say what building blocks you're limited to. If it isn't, please also say so and let us know if we can use stuff in SRFI-13 – [Daniel Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107331/daniel-martin) Sep 26 at 1:09
>
> ok yes it is homework, and I am limited to certain built in functions, Ill add them to my post ^ – Brian Sep 26 at 1:20

And then 10 days later on [Running time of stacking two queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868459/java-stack-help)

> Why no, I won't do your homework for you. But yes, I will help you once you're willing to put forth some effort on your end. – [AndyPerfect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343439/andyperfect) Oct 5 at 23:18
>
> its not homework, I am studying for a midterm and its an example in the text but theres no answer so I am asking you. – Brian Oct 5 at 23:45

Looks like the typical behaviour of someone trying to cover their tracks and not show the work of others as they ploddle to solve their end of chapter quizzes.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like an issue as well (screenshot of his recently-asked questions):

[image]