# How important is it to be specific in question titles?

Tags: discussion, questions

**I should begin by saying that this is not picking on someone particularly. I am presenting just a general thought concerning some standard way of writing question titles** 
Is it not important to  write our questions with as much specification as possible? If we ask very localized questions with general terms I feel it may mislead our searching for a specific topic or a general topic.

I will give some examples. 
In `stackoverflow.com`I have seen many questions on using `regular expression` in `Notepad++`. Most of them only have similar titles.

1. [Search for "word<>" and replace with "word=word1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301703/search-and-replace-regular-expression-in-notepad)
2. [Regex to find all hrefs that contain a path but no "." (dot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577328/regular-expression-in-notepad-ignore-if-contains?rq=1)
3. [Regex not matching text with newlines in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791240/notepad-regular-expressions?rq=1)
4. [Find lines matching regex and select a different part of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948377/notepad-regular-expression?rq=1)
5. [Search and append with regex in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206001/notepad-regular-regex?rq=1)
6. [Remove all lines that don't match regex in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092150/regex-in-notepad?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, it is important but you haven't really specified any thoughts; other than to note that the title's aren't particularly good. Also, bear in mind that there are over 3m questions which means that some will _always_ be nearly identical.

Comment: The reason why a better title can't be found (would be difficult to find) in those instances could be that the questions are too localised to extract some meaningful title?

Comment: @Charles: nice :)

Comment: @Charles: Thanks. I should honestly say I saw the title of this question but did not change it. May be it is because of laziness/lack of time that we do not try to be specific in writing the title. :)

Comment: [You tell me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ofAol.png) (Image taken from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67708/131713).)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is it important?  You bet!

The title of your question is *how* people find the question to begin with.  SO isn't just about helping people, it's also about building a repository of knowledge.  An excessively generic title, a confusing title, or even a verbose title can all be detrimental to people finding your question later and either helping you or learning from the question and answers.

If you find yourself asking a question, and you can't boil the main point of the question down into a concise, descriptive title, chances are that you need to give the question (and how it's being asked) more thought.

Answer (score 5):

> I am just asking what we need to keep in mind while forming the question title

See this Jakob Nielsen article.

[Microcontent: How to Write Headlines, Page Titles, and Subject Lines](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/980906.html)

> Microcontent needs to be pearls of clarity: you get 40-60 characters to explain your macrocontent. Unless the title or subject make it absolutely clear what the page or email is about, users will never open it.