# Discouraging uninformative question titles. The reason we should, and how can we?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find one of the useful features of Stack Exchange to be the 'RELATED' list.

However this is made a nonsense when users post questions like:

*Please can you answer this question?*

or

*What does this mean?*

These crop up all too regularly - especially in English Language. I'm not aware of a specific way to deal with such titles. Is there one? If not, can there please be one?

**Note**

I am aware of the existing question [How important is it to be specific in question titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/how-important-is-it-to-be-specific-in-question-titles); however this is posed from the point of view of the questioner.

My query is different - I'm looking for suggestions about what can be done about *others* who produce uninformative titles.

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure that SE has been trying to figure this out since the site first went live. As far as I know, the solution is to edit the questions and remind the asker to use more descriptive titles... Oh, and you can't duplicate an existing title, either.

Comment: How long did you spend tweaking the title to this question, just so it wasn't contradictory :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My query is different - I'm looking for suggestions about what can be done about others who produce uninformative titles.

Edit them. Give the question a decent title, one that lets people guess what the question is by looking at the title, and is searchable.

And comment. Let the user know that having a title is important. Feel free to link them to [How important is it to be specific in question titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/how-important-is-it-to-be-specific-in-question-titles).

Comment: Aha - I had given up trying to edit titles. Probably I didn't have sufficient privileges at the time. It worked for me just now on English Language.

Comment: People without full editing privileges can suggest edits. Titles don't even have the six-character minimum.

Answer (score 7):

To some extent, uninformative titles can be detected automatically but this requires a site-specific approach. On Mathematics, some community members were sufficiently tired of uninformative titles to

1. Collect the [signs of weak titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/retitling-questions-a-modest-proposal/8781#8781)
2. Write a [meta post on writing good titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)
3. Propose a [feature request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16573/) for automatic check
4. ... and it [was implemented](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17012/).

Not to say that the problem disappeared — terrible questions still have terrible titles — but the users writing decent questions got some just-in-time help.

Comment: you might be interested in checking another question about titles: [How to save the world… One question title at a time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201940/165773)