# People using their job title as the question title

Tags: discussion, user-interface, asking-questions, new-users, title

I've noticed a few instances recently where new users misinterpret the Title box of the Ask Question form as asking for their job title.  This results in questions with peculiar-looking titles like [I am a Phd student](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/258983/1).  The placeholder text in the title field ("What's your ... question? Be specific") apparently doesn't help everyone.

Usually someone will edit this (assuming the question itself is okay), but are there ways that this part of the interface could be more clear for people unfamiliar with the site, and whose English may be limited?

Comment: Is this something that happens on many sites, or are you thinking of one or two specific sites where this happens? I have never seen this on (e.g.) Arqade, MSE, or RPG.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I've seen it on MO and on Academia, I think.

Comment: sites that have this as a serious problem would likely benefit from learning from Math.SE folks [who try to establish a systemic approach to handling poor titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260981/165773)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs an update though clearly that user hasn't read the Help Center.

> but are there ways that this part of the interface could be more clear for people unfamiliar with the site, and whose English may be limited?

But I suppose some simpler, more direct English can be applied. Instead of the ""What's your ... question? Be specific"", the text could become something like this:

> Enter a phrase that specifically summarizes your problem

or

> Enter a phrase that specifically describes your current problem

---

But I think the current wording should be fine for new users, good or bad at English. New users are also greeted by other users, who sometimes tell the OP to visit the Help Center to help improve their post if their post is not currently in good shape. Like what @rene said:

> My point is that I doubt rephrasing would help...

Comment: *Enter a phrase that specifically summarizes your problem* I am a Phd student ...

Comment: @rene I don't really understand your point here

Comment: My point is that I doubt rephrasing would help ...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it needs an update. It would be very odd for a page on a q&a page to ask for your job title in order to ask a question. It makes no intuitive sense that it should, and much more intuitive sense that it's asking for the title of your question.

Such users aren't reading any other questions on the site, nor, apparently, are they reading the page directly in front of them. Next to "Title," the box reads: *What's your research-level mathematics question? Be specific.*

But more importantly, especially for non-English speakers, one can easily look at any other question on the site and see that a question comprises a title and a body. If their English is rough enough that this is difficult to parse (wholly possible, no fault of their own), then either the community just accepts the overhead of editing their question titles and bodies, something that would likely have to be done anyway, or they need to learn more English before they can really functionally use the site.